# Nginx Https Redirect with Trailing Slash and Query Parameters

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting

I have an Nginx server config that already redirects `http` requests to `https`, but I'm trying to figure out the proper way to modify this code or completely change it to redirect `http` requests to `https` **and** add a trailing forward slash `/`, when the url does not contain one. These redirects should also ensure that query parameters still exist despite the redirect. I have seen where most answers to similar questions to mine have referenced `^/(.*)/$` as the code for adding a forward slash, but I'm not sure how to use it and if I should use a `rewrite` over an `if`. Can anyone help clear up my confusion?

**nginx.config:**

```
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

}
```

**Goal:**

```
http://www.example.com/page-one -> http://example.com/page-one/
http://example.com/page-two -> https://www.example.com/page-two/
https://www.example.com/page-three?page=2 -> https://www.example.com/page-three/?page=2
```

Comment: The `rewrite` directive will append the query string to the rewritten URL, unless a trailing `?` is added.

Comment: Got it. That is good to know. Are you aware of the proper `rewrite` method to achieve what I'm asking above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three steps in your goals are each performed in different ways. The first step is best achieved using separate `server` blocks. The second step you already have in your question. The third step uses a `rewrite` statement.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    return http://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name example.com;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") { return 301 https://$host$request_uri; }

    rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

    ...
}
```

The existing query string is also appended to the rewritten URL. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: Richard thank you for this answer. Since I'm rolling this out as a script to multiple domains (e.g. `http://staging.example.com` and `https://www.example.com`) is it necessary to add the first server block that strictly identifies the hostname? I tried your code without the first block and the `rewrite` works as intended, but it looks like it is adding a forward slash to all assets as well as URLs. I guess I need to add a separate line or modify the rewrite to prevent files from receiving this.

Comment: To achieve goal #1, you could use a regex on `$host` inside an `if` statement. The `rewrite` rule processes every URI without a trailing `/`, so how are the URIs of your assets different from the URIs that need a trailin `/`?

Comment: Thank you for the additional help. Would it be possible to switch `http://example.com` with `$host` instead of the `if` statement? What is different about the assets is that this is rewriting after an extension and breaking the location lookup. E.g. asset is found at `https://www.example.com/image/logo.svg`, but the rewrite is adding `/` after the `.svg`, `https://www.example.com/image/logo.svg/` and the image is rendered as broken.

Comment: You need a regular expression that matches only those URIs that need a trailing `/`. If `$host` contains `www.` you will need to use a regular expression to capture the non-www hostname.